# Problem with references in php5

Tags: php, class, object, reference

Let me start right off the code:

```
<?php
class Father{
    function Father(){
        echo 'A wild Father appears..';
    }

    function live(){
        echo 'Some Father feels alive!';
    }
}

class Child{
    private $parent;
    function Child($p){
        echo 'A child is born :)';
    }

    function setParent($p){
        $parent = $p;
    }

    function dance(){
        echo 'The child is dancing, when ';
        $parent -> live();
    }
}

$p = new Father();
$p -> live();
$c = new Child($p);
$c -> dance();

?>
```

When running this I get an error on Line 24 saying "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function live() on a non-object in ../test.php on line 24"
I've searched the web for a while now and can't find a solution for this to work.
Can someone help me with my poor understanding of php5?

Comment: Did you know that constructors should be named `__construct` instead of `NameOfTheClass` in PHP5?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm just learning the language since I've got to write something in it for a project. Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$this->parent->live()` to access the member variable. Additionally, you have to assign the parent object to it.

```
class Child{
    private $parent;
    function __construct($p){
        echo 'A child is born :)';
        $this->parent = $p; // you could also call setParent() here
    }

    function setParent($p){
        $this->parent = $p;
    }

    function dance(){
        echo 'The child is dancing, when ';
        $this->parent -> live();
    }
}
```

Besides that, you should rename your constructor methods to `__construct` which is the suggested name in PHP5.

Comment: Aah! That's good to know :) - 9 Minutes to go until this may become the solution ^^

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call `setParent` in your constructor.
This will fix it:

```
function Child($p){
    echo 'A child is born :)';
    $this->setParent($p);
}
```

Comment: Usually getters/setters are for the external interface and internally accessing the field directly is better.

Answer (score 0):

First, the preferred method to use constructor in PHP5 by using __construct keyword.
When you access to class member you should to use `$this`, witch in your case you didn't when you tried to `parent` member.

```
function setParent($p){
        $parent = $p;
    }
```

Make it like this:

```
function setParent($p){
        $this->parent = $p;
    }
```

And this:

```
   function dance(){
        echo 'The child is dancing, when ';
        $parent -> live();
    }
```

To this:

```
   function dance(){
        echo 'The child is dancing, when ';
        $this->parent -> live();
    }
```

You will be end with this:

```
$p = new Father();
$p -> live();
$c = new Child();
$c -> setParent($p);
$c -> dance();
```

You don't need pass the parent to the child constructor as you will set it in `setParent` method.